# how to find out the index of a number in R

Tags: r

I am going to find out the index of the number that is near 1.609. It should be the second number of the vector:

```
[1] 1.58150107   
[2] 1.60150107
[3] 1.62150107   
[4] 1.64150107   
[5] 1.66150107
[6] 1.68150107   
[7] 1.70150107
```

how can I find it in R?

Thank you!

Comment: `which.min(abs(x - 1.609))` __OR__ `which(abs(x - 1.609) == min(abs(x - 1.609)))`

Comment: Thanks for your advice! @bouncyball and kevmo314

Comment: If the numbers are always sorted, consider `findInterval()`